# How to use mathematical operations while subsetting in R without creating new datasets

Tags: r, subset, atomic, mean

I want to take differences of mean without creating a new dataset and instead just subsetting as I go along. Here is my attempt

```
temp <- c("low","low","med","med","low","low","med","med")
species <- c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B")
abundance <- c(1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4)

dat <- cbind(temp,species,abundance)

datdiff <- mean(dat[dat$temp == "low"& dat$species == "A",]$abundance) - mean(dat[dat$temp == "low"& dat$species == "B",]$abundance)
```

I get an error that says `

> Error in dat$temp : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Any suggestions on how I can write this differently?

Comment: You data is a matrix not a dataframe, try converting it to a dataframe then run

Comment: Replace `cbind` with `data.frame`.

Comment: Thanks! That solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your data is not a data.frame its a `matrix`.

If you do this , it should work.

```
dat <- data.frame(dat, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
# or as suggested by @G. Grothendieck in the comments, use dat <- data.frame(temp = temp,species = species,abundance = abundance, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat$abundance <- as.numeric(dat$abundance) #convert here it as numeric to get statistical outputs.
mean(dat[dat$temp == "low"& dat$species == "A",]$abundance) - mean(dat[dat$temp == "low"& dat$species == "B",]$abundance)
```

**Output:**

```
[1] -1
```